# Finding overriding methods

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, can I find which methods override the method declaration on focus now?

Scenario: When I'm viewing a method in a base class (which interface), I would like to know where the method is overriden (or implemented).  Now I just make the method `final` and see where I get the errors, but it is not perfect.

Note: I know about `class hierarchy` views, but I don't want to go through all the subclasses to find which ones use a custom implementation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Select the method and click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Alternatively, right-click on it and select `Quick Type Hierachy`.

*removed dead ImageShack link - Screenshot*

Comment: Works great and handles both cases I wanted!  You can view it also by opening the context window (i.e. right-click on method declaration) and selecting `Quick Type Hierarchy`.

Answer (score 2):

Select the method declaration and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to see all declarations.

To see only the declarations inherited by the subject, `right-click->Declarations->Hierarchy`.

Comment: Very close, but this returns all methods that match the given signature, even if they are completely unrelated.

Comment: Updated for the specific search for the type hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

Right-click -> Declarations (Keybord shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> for searching the whole workspace).